# Magento 2: How to manage simple user (customer) login session for different device?

Tags: magento2.2, login, customer-account, customer-session, sessions

Using `Magento 2.2`, I need to allow customer login only `one device` at a time. Ex. if the customer is already logged in the `computer`, but user tries to log in with a `smartphone`, the Magento will disconnect them from the computer?

Answer (score 0):

For check user login or not :

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
   // login action
}
```

To check in  controller

```
$this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
}
```

As based on this you can check where customer login or not and put condition according to your requirement.

Comment: How to know who is login?

Comment: If user `jonh` login in web, then he want log in to phone. How to verify `jonh` is loged?